# Warning : RVM used Gemfile selecting Ruby"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rvm

When i go to into my directory in the terminal i get this warning.How do fix it .I am running my app on heroku too so i am wondering if there is any conflict between heroku and something installed on the system

```
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /Users/Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'
```

.

Comment: Suggested edit queue is full. Any @mod available?

Answer (score 7):

Do exactly what it's telling you to ignore the warning:

```
rvm rvmrc warning ignore /Users/Gemfile
```

You will no longer see the warning after that.

Answer (score 3):

If this is all you get then it's fine.

You defined a ruby version in your Gemfile. The warning just states the fact that rvm uses that version.

Comment: But, why a warning? if all it's fine why warn?

Comment: It does bear the question: is there another, preferred, way of specifying the Ruby version?